# Нужный знак препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, какой знак препинания лучше поставить в этом предложении после слова "Чечню": тире или двоеточие?
**Я открываю людям новую для них Чечню: со снежными горными вершинами, альпийскими лугами, удивительными озерами и водопадами, древними башенными комплексами.**

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не было бы формальной ошибкой употребление двоеточия (раскрытие содержания введённого понятия "новая Чечня") и даже запятой (уточнение), но по содержанию здесь желателен более сильный акцент: отделяемая часть информации несёт в себе декларированный перед этим элемент новизны (или даже неожиданности) для читателей ("людей"). Здесь как бы вводится и тут же употребляется определение новой (для читателей, "людей") Чечни: *"новая Чечня - это Чечня со снежными..."*. Такое определение само по себе содержит тире, разделяющее отождествляемые сущности. Поэтому **тире** здесь предпочтительно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Alex! Очень разумный ответ, он мне очень помог.

Answer (score 1):

Я открываю людям новую для них Чечню (какую?) ― **со снежными горными вершинами, альпийскими лугами, удивительными озерами и водопадами, древними башенными комплексами.**

Это обособленный с помощью тире **ряд несогласованных определений**. Двоеточие в таких конструкциях обычно не ставится  (выбор между двоеточием и тире, как правило,  делается в сложном бессоюзном предложении или при наличии обобщающего слова).

Comment: Спасибо большое!